# Clicking a link doesn't redirect? How to debug ui-router?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

I scaffolded an ionic V1 site using tab template and created the following link in a page.

```
<a href="#/tab/Test">
  Test
</a>
```

And an empty control for "Test" page.

```
.controller('TestCtrl', function ($scope) {
})
```

The following is the router

```
  .state('tab.test', {
    url: '/test',
    views: {
      'tab-test': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/tab-test.html',
        controller: 'TestCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
```

However, when testing using `ionic serve`, click the link doesn't go to the page. It stays in the page but the URL in the address bar changed to `localhost:8100/#/tab/test`.

Full router.

```
  .config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    // Ionic uses AngularUI Router which uses the concept of states
    // Learn more here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router
    // Set up the various states which the app can be in.
    // Each state's controller can be found in controllers.js
    $stateProvider

      .state('login', {
        url: '/login',
        templateUrl: 'templates/login.html',
        controller: 'LoginCtrl'
      })

      .state('events', {
        url: '/events',
        templateUrl: 'templates/events.html',
        controller: 'EventsCtrl'
      })

      // setup an abstract state for the tabs directive
      .state('tab', {
        url: '/tab',
        abstract: true,
        templateUrl: 'templates/tabs.html'
      })

      .state('tab.settings', {
        url: '/settings',
        views: {
          'tab-settings': {
            templateUrl: 'templates/tab-settings.html',
            controller: 'SettingsCtrl'
          }
        }
      })

      .state('tab.test', {
        url: '/test',
        views: {
          'tab-test': {
            templateUrl: 'templates/tab-test.html',
            controller: 'TestCtrl'
          }
        }
      })

      .state('tab.venues', {
        url: '/venues',
        views: {
          'tab-venues': {
            templateUrl: 'templates/tab-venues.html',
            controller: 'VenuesCtrl'
          }
        }
      })

      // Each tab has its own nav history stack:

      .state('tab.events', {
        url: '/events',
        views: {
          'tab-events': {
            templateUrl: 'templates/tab-events.html',
            controller: 'EventsCtrl'
          }
        }
      })

      .state('tab.categories', {
        url: '/categories',
        views: {
          'tab-categories': {
            templateUrl: 'templates/tab-categories.html',
            controller: 'CategoriesCtrl'
          }
        }
      })

      .state('tab.chats', {
        url: '/chats',
        views: {
          'tab-chats': {
            templateUrl: 'templates/tab-chats.html',
            controller: 'ChatsCtrl'
          }
        }
      })
      .state('tab.chat-detail', {
        url: '/chats/:chatId',
        views: {
          'tab-chats': {
            templateUrl: 'templates/chat-detail.html',
            controller: 'ChatDetailCtrl'
          }
        }
      })

      .state('tab.account', {
        url: '/account',
        views: {
          'tab-account': {
            templateUrl: 'templates/tab-account.html',
            controller: 'AccountCtrl'
          }
        }
      });

    // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');

  });
```

**Update:**

It will works if I change the router to the following. But it will be full screen and the tabs are gone.

```
  .state('test', {
    url: '/test',
    templateUrl: 'templates/tab-test.html',
    controller: 'TestCtrl'
  })
```

and the link href to `href="#/privacy"`.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `href` url `href="#/test'"` instead of `href="#/tab/Test"`

Comment: It goes `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');` after change it to `href="#/test'".

Comment: Please post your full route configuration

Comment: did you inject your controller script file in layout page? and did you get any console error?

Answer (score 0):

I am using this code

```
<ion-tab  title="" icon-off="ion-ios-home-outline" icon-on="ion-ios-home" href="#/tab/test" ng-if="userkey">
    <ion-nav-view name="tab-test"></ion-nav-view>
</ion-tab>
```

if you want to navigate 
< ion-nav-view name=**"tab-test"**>

and state name sould be same

.state('tab.test', {
    url: '/test',
    views: {
      **'tab-test'**: {
        templateUrl: 'templates/tab-test.html',
        controller: 'TestCtrl'
      }
    }
  })

Comment: This will need to create a new tab icon in the tab bar. But I don't want to create a icon for "Test"?